# Using "runas" command from PHP

Tags: php, browser, runas

This question is related to: [Using "runas" command for a program that writes a file (Windows Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999086/using-runas-command-for-a-program-that-writes-a-file-windows-server-2008)

I tried to run the `runas` command from PHP to run that console program:

```
<?php
exec("runas /savecred /user:User1 writeTxt.exe");
?>
```

But it doesn't work when called from a browser. However, it works by running it in PHP interactive mode (`php -a`). Is there anything that must be set in the browser for this?

Comment: Try `phpinfo();` and search for the safe_mode directive(s). Is safe_mode active?

Comment: Is it `sql.safe_mode`? If yes, it's already off. However, it's already removed since PHP 5.4.0 (my version is 5.4.19): [PHP:Safe Mode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)

Comment: It should be simply `safe_mode`. Edit: Sorry, forgot Safe Mode has been removed. Never mind.

Comment: A related question is this: [exec - Running command-line application from PHP as specific user - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user). How to do this in Windows?

Comment: I suspect `runas` doesn't work in PHP run on a browser since the command (`runas.exe`) is inside the `Windows\system32` directory. A question: does the internet user account in Windows (`IUSR`) have a read & execute permission for the `system32` folder? Does anybody know about this?

Comment: I did found a some way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666449/how-to-run-executable-from-php-website-as-a-specific-windows-user

Answer (score 0):

If I call `runas` without the `/savecred` parameter using `exec()` in PHP (from a browser), the program `writeTxt.exe` doesn't produce any result. It seems that there's no mechanism for the browser to ask the user's password for `runas`.

In the PHP interactive mode, once the user's password has been supplied for `runas`, the usage of `/savecred` will cause the program to be executed directly without asking for password. Obviously, the PHP interactive mode is a different session from the browser's PHP. Since the browser doesn't have a mechanism to ask for user's password for `runas`, `/savecred` is apparently useless for the browser session.

Regarding my comment about the `IUSR` permission for `system32` folder, I've tested it using this code:

```
<?php
exec("whoami");            // whoami.exe is in the system32 folder
?>
```

The browser will display `IUSR`. So `IUSR` has a read & execute access to the `system32` folder.

Comment: So did you find a solution? Please share if you did.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked on this for quite a long time. Actually this question was "born" because I want to run Microsoft Speech SDK console application using PHP: [Running Windows Speech SDK Application in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956680/running-windows-speech-sdk-application-in-php).