# How to run executable from PHP website as a specific Windows user?

Tags: php, command-line, exec, psexec, runas

By default PHP runs under **IUSR** account. When executed directly:

```
$lastline = exec('D:\\MyProgram.exe', $output, $return_var);
```

It runs, but the program is unable to do it's tasks due to insufficient privileges. My question is: **How do I run an executable under a specific Windows account from a PHP website?**

### I've tried:

When executed through [Sysinternals PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553):

```
$lastline = exec('D:\\PsExec.exe -u UserName -p Password -accepteula "D:\\MyProgram.exe"', $output, $return_var);
```

MyProgram.exe does not even execute at all. PHP throws empty output and return_var is `-1073741502`. I assume this is some sort of unhandled exception.

---

When executed through [lsrunas](http://www.moernaut.com/default.aspx?item=lsrunas):

```
$lastline = exec('D:\\lsrunas.exe /user:UserName /password:Password /domain:DOMAIN /command:"D:\\MyProgram.exe" /runpath:D:\\', $output, $return_var);
```

MyProgram.exe does not execute either. PHP throws empty output and return_var is `0`.

---

Microsoft's built in `runas` command doesn't work because it doesn't accept password as a parameter.

---

Tried using different PHP functions like `shell_exec`, `system` and `passthru`

---

Tried creating a new Application Pool under IIS, to run the website under LOCAL SERVICE, SYSTEM, or a specific user.
EDIT: This is where I went wrong. It should work, but fails when Load User Profile setting is not enabled (step 3 in my answer).

**Does anyone have working suggestions?**

*Note: All commands are working and tested through command line directly.*

Comment: I think you can "pipe" password to `runas` - something like `exec('echo adminpassword | runas /user:administrator fullPathToProgram',$output);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept digging and found out that the only thing that works is a dedicated application pool.

1. Create a new Application Pool under IIS
2. Set username and password in `Advanced Settings > Identity > Custom account`
3. Set `Advanced Settings > Load User Profile` to **`true`** (this one is important)
4. Choose this pool under Basic Settings of a site,

-or-  for a better security:

. 5.Move all command-relatied code to one section within your website, convert it to application and apply that Application Pool to it. Then you can restrict any public access to that part and safely call that functionality from the other parts of your site.

**Important note (!):**

If you're running PHP via FastCGI, you must set `fastcgi.impersonate = 0` in `php.ini` file.

---

### Test batch file:

To test who is running the process you can save the following code to a `*.bat` file and call it from PHP.

```
@echo off
SET now=%date% %time%
SET out=[%now%] %userdomain%\%username%
echo %out%
echo %out% > D:\hello.txt
::msg * "%out%"

if %username%=="SpecificUser" (
  exit /B 100
) else (
  exit /B 200
)
```

Replace `SpecificUser` with your desired user name. Sometimes you'll see no output. The exit codes will help you then.

In case you can't see any output or exit code at all, this script will output the username to a text file. Replace `D:\hello.txt` with your desired path.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! For anyone who may have run into my problem: When I attempted this solution using PHP's shell_exec() function the batch file kept returning the "nt authority\IUSR".  I found that using PHP's proc_open() function used the account specified in the Application Pool. Just a heads up - proc_open() has issues with spaces in folder paths that can be solved by putting a double quote at very beginning and end of the $cmd string.