# Call Perl script from PHP

Tags: php, perl, iis

I am using the following statements to execute a Perl script from a web site using PHP.

```
$perl = shell_exec('perl '.$dest.'/script.pl 2>&1 '.$mail.' '.str_replace("/", "\\", $dest));
```

I want to run the script server side, but it seems that it uses the Perl that is installed on the client so someone that has not installed Perl could not run the script.

I can't figure out what I am missing.

EDIT:
I run:

> $perl = shell_exec('C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -v');

and figure out that was Perl server side running. So now I have to understand why some clients can't execute script.

EDIT 2:
It is definitely a permission issue, only administrator could write. I' ll manage the permission.

Comment: Use full path to execute the script.

Comment: example: exec("/usr/bin/perl /full/path/to/Script.pl $username $password",$output);

Comment: You can't make your server run code on the client outside of what the browser does (e.g. JavaScript or XSLT). That's not how the web works.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that it uses the client's Perl? Do you have any error messages or log entries? Please [edit] your question and add these things.

Comment: Also, where do `$dest` and `$mail` come from? If they come out of parameters to your PHP program and you have not properly sanitised them, you could introduce a massive security problem. A malicious person could for example submit the string `" && rm -rf foo #"`, where `foo` could be any directory. This is similar to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), but potentially way worse as an attacker could delete potentially your whole server.

Comment: IIS uses the Perl installed on the server, if it can find it. It cannot use software installed on the client.

Comment: @Tegito: An HTTP server will not mistake the client file system for the server file system just because it has been given relative paths. Please withdraw your misleading comments.

Comment: @Tegito : I tried the full path both of Perl exe and script but with no luck.

Comment: @simbabque : thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: *"It is definitely a permission issue"* Does that mean you have this fixed, or at least know enough to fix it?

Comment: @Borodin I've found that adminstrators could write and execute in the folder i create to run the script. Normal user who execute the script run under nt authority\network service. This user can't execute or write. I'm following this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666449 that appears to have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility that the IIS server is running `perl.exe` on the client machine. The HTTP protocol doesn't provide for anything like that

You don't say *why* you think this is happening, so we can't help you any further

I can only suggest that you're using the same machine for both client and server and have confused yourself

Comment: The only thing that make me suppose IIS was running client side Perl is that only user with Perl installed on their pc can run correctly the script. Server (windows server ) and client are separated. I thought of permission issue but all user can write into the folder where the script is.

Comment: @Giovanni: It doesn't matter whether it's IIS or something else. One system cannot cause a program to be executed on another system without something specially coded to do that. You need to explain why you think this is happening.

Comment: I only supposed that cause I can’t figure out why on some clients it is not working. Is there something to check or to post that I could do?